# "Though" vs. "although"

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

Can we use *though* and *although* interchangeably? Somebody told me that the difference is that *though* cannot be used at the beginning of a sentence. Is that the rule?

Answer (score 22):

*Though* can definitely be used at the beginning of a sentence, and has a long history of doing so. Consider Isaiah 1:18 from the King James Bible:

> Though your sins be as scarlet, they shall be as white as snow; though they be red like crimson, they shall be as wool.

TheFreeDictionary.com cites this usage rule:

> Although and though are interchangeable as conjunctions, but to start a clause, use although.

However, this seems overly fussy and prescriptive. Consider the following:

> I went ahead and chopped all the wood, though no one told me to.
>
> You left without your luggage, though I can't imagine why.

Those sound to me like perfectly fine English. They would be perfectly fine using *although* as well. That, to me, feels like interchangeability, pure and simple. In fact,
I can think of no examples in which *though* cannot be used interchangeably with *although*. Though your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 12):

http://grammarist.com/usage/although-though/

As conjunctions, *although* and *though* are interchangeable. *Although* is generally considered more formal than *though*, though both forms appear regularly in both formal and informal writing.

*Though* is also an adverb, meaning *however* or *nevertheless*. In this sense, *though* is not interchangeable with *although*, which is only a conjunction.

And in these examples, *though* is an adverb and hence not interchangeable with *although*:

> This weekend, **though**, theaters were packed. [Los Angeles Times]
>
> There was another twist to come, **though**, as Pavlyuchenkova defied her
>   flagging fortunes to win three games in succession.  [Independent]

http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/although-versus-while.aspx

In fact, “though” came before “although.” In the 1300s, before “although” became one word, it was two words —“all” and “though”— with the “all” there to add emphasis to “though (5, 6).”

Comment: Upvoted for the distinction between "though" as a conjunction and "though" as an adverb. Excellent job.

Comment: +1 for 'although' suggests a stronger contrast than 'though'. Also mentioned at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-though-and-although/

Answer (score 2):

H.W. Fowler, *Modern English Usage*, revised edition (1965) offers a concise and generally valid summary of the differences between *though* and *although*:

> *Though, although.* The definite differences between the two hardly need stating. They are: first that *though* can and *although* cannot be used an adverb, placed last (*He said he would come; he didn't, though*); and secondly that *though* is alone possible in the *as though* idiom. In the use common to both forms, i.e. as a complete conjunction, no definite line can be drawn between them, and either is always admissible. But it is safe to say, in the first place, that *though* is much commoner, and, secondly, that the conditions in which *although* is likely to occur are (a) in the more formal style of writing, (b) in a clause that does not follow but precedes the main sentence, and perhaps (c) in stating an established fact rather than a mere hypothesis [examples omitted].

I'm not at all sure about item (c) above, but the rest seems reasonably accurate in the present day. (Fowler made these points originally in 1926, in the first edition of his book.) Especially noteworthy is how Fowler turns on its head the supposed rule about never starting a sentence with *though*: according to Fowler, the point isn't that you can't start a sentence with *though*, but that the start of a sentence is a situation where *although* is relatively likely to occur. Fowler's overriding contention is that *though* is much more commonly used than *although*—a state of affairs that was truer in Fowler's day than it is now, to judge from this Ngram chart of *though* (blue line) versus *although* (red line) for the years 1700–2000:

[image]

The discussion of *though* and *although* in Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) indicates how little had changed between 1965 (or indeed 1926) and 2003:

> **although; though.** As conjunctions the words are virtually interchangeable. The only distinction is that *although* is more formal and dignified, *though* more usual in speech and familiar writing. In certain formal contexts, however, *though* reads better. *Though* serves also as an adverb [example omitted].

Garner doesn't include an example of a formal context in which *though* reads better than *although* as a conjunction, though I don't doubt that he could have done so. I am quite familiar with the shift in tone between habitual use of *though* and habitual use of *although*. For more than a decade I copyedited textbooks and university press books whose publishers strongly favored *although*; when I switched to magazine work, I was disconcerted at first by the many instances of *though* that appeared in manuscripts.

Ultimately, what sold me on *though* was how much easier it was to work with during copyfitting, the process of cutting lines and altering words to get a story to fit into its available layout space. You wouldn't think that an eight-letter word would be much more difficult to accommodate than a six-letter word—especially when one of the letters is an l—but you'd be wrong. Often I have run into situations where *although* wouldn't fit even on a heavily kerned line and would leave the line with an unsightly gappiness between the remaining words when it rolled over to the next line, but where *though* worked fine. (Our house style forbade hyphenation after two letters, so it was all or nothing with *although*.) Anyway, that's how I came to appreciate the special charms of *though*, and it's why I've long appreciated the interchangeability of *though* and *although* when used as conjunctions.

Answer (score 1):

Although is a more proactive word then though, they mean the same thing but saying although, gets your attention much better then just saying though

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SAT, that though cannot be used when starting a sentence is definite not the case.

See:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pages are a little difficult to read, and they all seem to be questions. Could you not copy questions 7, 16 and the middle one in the 3rd photo? EDIT: But I see copying the format would be impossible using the edit tools available here. Perhaps you could crop the photos and copy the sentences below each image?

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty much it. The two are practically interchangeable; however, care must be taken when using though because it has several other uses.